# css combination fail to get the output for my image

Tags: javascript, css

have that problem, that if i click on my image to zoom in (.myImg class) my image is loading and showing a while a error message which i cant read before the page reload itself. but the main problem is that i can't find the problem why it doesnt show me the zoom of the image. if i try to load the image alone without all the other classes it works. i think the problem is between the different classes but i cant figure out where. =/ thx for any idea

```js
 var certs = [
  { nr:       ['0'], name:       ['test'],
    pfadPic:    ['https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/'],
    picName:    ['4070813-confused-smilie-smiley-confused-confused-smiliepnghtml-smilie-png-528_473_preview.png'],
    nameForPic: ['hmmm'],
    classPic:   ['myImg tooltiptext'],
    classATag:  ['tooltip'],
  },
]
      
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]
var html = ''
var n = 0
var i = 0
      
html += 
            '<ul>'
          +   '<li><a href="">test</a>'
          +     '<ul>' 
          +       '<li><a href="">test</a>'
          +         '<ul>'
       +           '<li><a href="" class="'+certs[n].classATag[0]+'" >'+certs[n].nameForPic[i]+'<img class="'+certs[n].classPic[0]+'" src="' + certs[n].pfadPic + certs[n].picName[i] + '" ></a></li>'
          +         '</ul>'
          +       '</li>' 
          +     '</ul>' 
          +   '</li>' 
          + '</ul>' 
      menu.innerHTML = html
```

```css
/* CSS Text hover */
      .tooltip {
        border-bottom:    1px dotted black;
        display:          inline-block;
        position:         relative;
      }
      .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        background-color: black;
        border-radius:    6px;
        color:            #fff;
        text-align:       center;
        padding:          5px 0;
        position:         absolute;
        visibility:       hidden;
        width:            400px;
        z-index:          1;
      }
      .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility:       visible;
      }
/* CSS Bildzoomer */
      .myImg {
        border-radius:   5px;
        cursor:       pointer;
        margin-top:   5px;
        transition:   0.3s;
      }
      .myImg:hover {
        opacity:    0.7;
        z-index:            2;  
      }
      .modal {
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
        display:none; 
        height:100%; 
        left: 0;
        overflow:auto; 
        padding-top:100px; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0;
        width:100%; 
        z-index:2; 
      }
      .modal-content {
        display:block;
        margin: auto;
        max-width:1000px;
        width:  80%;
      }
      #caption {
        color:  #ccc;
        display: block;
        height: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 700px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align: center;
        width:  80%;
      }
      .modal-content, #caption {
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
        to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
      }
      @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform: scale(0)}
        to {transform: scale(1)}
      }
      .close {
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        right: 35px;
        top: 15px;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      .close:hover,
      .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
/* CSS Dropdown Menü */
      .menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;        /* hilft dabei, dss das submenü sich exakt an das menü anpasst */
      }
      .menu ul li{
        background-color:   #34495E;
        border-right:       5px solid #f1c40f; 
        border-top:         1px solid #BDC3C7; 
        cursor:             pointer;
        transition:         all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        -o-transition:      all 0.3s;
        position:           relative;
        vertical-align:     middle;
        width:              100px;     /* Standard sind 200px */
      }
      .menu ul li:hover {
        background-color:   #2ecc71;
      }
      .menu > ul > li {               /* sagt aus menu zu ul zu li soll das tun */
        border-right:       5px solid #f1c40f;
      }
      .menu ul ul {
        border-left:        5px solid #f1c40f;
        left:               100%;     /* versetzt das submenu nach rechts */
        opacity:            0;
        position:           absolute; /* versteckt das 2te ul menu */
        transition:         all 0.3s;
        top:                -2%;      /* versetzt das menü nach oben auf die gleiche ebene */
        visibility:         hidden;   /*  */
      }
      .menu ul li:hover > ul {
        opacity:            1;        /* macht das submenü sichtbar */ 
        visibility:         visible;  /* macht das submenü sichtbar */
      }
      .menu ul li a {
        color:              #fff;
        text-decoration:    none;
        pointer:            cursor;
      }
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the anchor tag 'href' attribute. The function 'removeClass' is missing.

```js
var certs = [
  { nr:       ['0'], name:       ['test'],
    pfadPic:    ['https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/'],
    picName:    ['4070813-confused-smilie-smiley-confused-confused-smiliepnghtml-smilie-png-528_473_preview.png'],
    nameForPic: ['hmmm'],
    classPic:   ['myImg tooltiptext'],
    classATag:  ['tooltip'],
  },
]
      
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]
var html = ''
var n = 0
var i = 0
      
html += 
            '<ul>'
          +   '<li><a href="">test</a>'
          +     '<ul>' 
          +       '<li><a href="">test</a>'
          +         '<ul>'
       +           '<li><a href="#" class="'+certs[n].classATag[0]+'" onclick="removeClass('+certs[n].classATag[0]+')">'+certs[n].nameForPic[i]+'<img class="'+certs[n].classPic[0]+'" src="' + certs[n].pfadPic + certs[n].picName[i] + '" ></a></li>'
          +         '</ul>'
          +       '</li>' 
          +     '</ul>' 
          +   '</li>' 
          + '</ul>' 
      menu.innerHTML = html
```

```css
/* CSS Text hover */
      .tooltip {
        border-bottom:    1px dotted black;
        display:          inline-block;
        position:         relative;
      }
      .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        background-color: black;
        border-radius:    6px;
        color:            #fff;
        text-align:       center;
        padding:          5px 0;
        position:         absolute;
        visibility:       hidden;
        width:            400px;
        z-index:          1;
      }
      .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility:       visible;
      }
/* CSS Bildzoomer */
      .myImg {
        border-radius:   5px;
        cursor:       pointer;
        margin-top:   5px;
        transition:   0.3s;
      }
      .myImg:hover {
        opacity:    0.7;
        z-index:            2;  
      }
      .modal {
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
        display:none; 
        height:100%; 
        left: 0;
        overflow:auto; 
        padding-top:100px; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0;
        width:100%; 
        z-index:2; 
      }
      .modal-content {
        display:block;
        margin: auto;
        max-width:1000px;
        width:  80%;
      }
      #caption {
        color:  #ccc;
        display: block;
        height: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 700px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align: center;
        width:  80%;
      }
      .modal-content, #caption {
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
        to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
      }
      @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform: scale(0)}
        to {transform: scale(1)}
      }
      .close {
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        right: 35px;
        top: 15px;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      .close:hover,
      .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
/* CSS Dropdown Menü */
      .menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;        /* hilft dabei, dss das submenü sich exakt an das menü anpasst */
      }
      .menu ul li{
        background-color:   #34495E;
        border-right:       5px solid #f1c40f; 
        border-top:         1px solid #BDC3C7; 
        cursor:             pointer;
        transition:         all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        -o-transition:      all 0.3s;
        position:           relative;
        vertical-align:     middle;
        width:              100px;     /* Standard sind 200px */
      }
      .menu ul li:hover {
        background-color:   #2ecc71;
      }
      .menu > ul > li {               /* sagt aus menu zu ul zu li soll das tun */
        border-right:       5px solid #f1c40f;
      }
      .menu ul ul {
        border-left:        5px solid #f1c40f;
        left:               100%;     /* versetzt das submenu nach rechts */
        opacity:            0;
        position:           absolute; /* versteckt das 2te ul menu */
        transition:         all 0.3s;
        top:                -2%;      /* versetzt das menü nach oben auf die gleiche ebene */
        visibility:         hidden;   /*  */
      }
      .menu ul li:hover > ul {
        opacity:            1;        /* macht das submenü sichtbar */ 
        visibility:         visible;  /* macht das submenü sichtbar */
      }
      .menu ul li a {
        color:              #fff;
        text-decoration:    none;
        pointer:            cursor;
      }
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: @nisanath-sojan hi sry. no it isn't. i just forgot to remoe that part, because i tried to remove after clicking the class from it to figure out if i could remove the problem with that, but it wasn't the solution. but ha. i tried to remove the href ans look at that it works. thx for the solution!